# How to create function for an API function not belonging to any model class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I am using Django/DRF for my backend and I want the client (my web app) to be able to make an API call that looks up tags for an image using Google Cloud Vision API. Obviously, I don't want the client to have access to the API key, hence the server should perform the actual call to Google's API. What I'm struggling with currently is where to put this API function. Do I have to create a model for this (even though there is no db table) or is there some way around that?

Comment: what have you tried? at first sight and with any info i would suggest to do the calls in your views set.

Comment: @efkin I haven't tried anything because I can't figure out where to put the function. For example, if I make a POST call inside a ViewSet, it would require tying this function to some object that it doesn't necessarily belong to (for example, there is no primary key).

Comment: i see... i guess you do have a model for your image model and you do store tags related to the image. So you could tie the GCV API call to the Image model.

Comment: @efkin The way I was envisioning this wouldn't require anything to be persisted until the user makes the final decision to upload the image. The call to GCV is simply to make it easier for the user to select tags that are automatically generated. After that step, the user does not necessarily have to upload the image (although I think where you're going is that I could post it in the background regardless).

Comment: @EvanZamir: Why do you "absolutely" need DRF usage in the first place ? 
You could write a good old function based view to access GCV API with django as a proxy.

You want to user DRF, you can write your own view using "views.APIView". File upload is from memory a pain to handle thought.

Comment: @JulienKieffer I am using DRF for the rest of my project (no pun intended), so I figured it makes sense to be consistent. But I guess you have a point. Maybe that's the way I have to go.

Comment: @JulienKieffer Thanks, that sounds like the way to go. I already have file handling working. In this case should be even easier since it's just a url.